# Change Responsive Images Maximum Width of 1600px

Tags: theme-development, responsive, images

Sorry for my English first.
Just started with responsive Images and read

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/

So according to this post, there is a maximum width of 1.600px. I wonder how to increase this value to 1800px? And if it's possible... .

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove that limit, go to your `functions.php` and add this code.

```
function remove_max_srcset_image_width( $max_width ) {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'remove_max_srcset_image_width' );
```

If you want to increase, go to your `functions.php` and add this code.

```
function custom_max_srcset_image_width( $max_width, $size_array ) {
    $max_width = 1800;
    return $max_width;
}
add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'custom_max_srcset_image_width');
```